# How to filter Data using email in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

How can I get data by email from MongoDB? Here is an example:

```
       _id: Objectid('6274e58826914a298567e5f8'),
        "name": "Vauxhall Mokka",
        "supplier": "Vauxhall",
        "email": "abc@def.com",
        "price": 30000,
        "quantity": 30,
        "img": "https://i.ibb.co/SQqBNXy/getImage.png",
        "sold": 0
```

I can easily get the item by _id with this code:

```
 app.get('/cars/:id', async (req, res) => {
            const id = req.params.id;
            const query = { _id: ObjectId(id) };
            const result = await serviceCollection.findOne(query);
            res.send(result);
        });
```

But why I couldn't do the same with email? when I apply `'/cars/:email'`, the server goes down. If I get the item with id, then why cannot get it with the email?

Comment: How do you write the email into URL? Like `/cars/user@example.com`? Try to URL-encode the at-sign: `/cars/user%40example.com`. It is however very unusual to write email into URL path. Rather place it in query string (`/cars/filter?email=user%40example.com`) and read it from `req.query.email`.

You should properly escape special characters (at-sign has special meaning in URL), so

Answer (score 0):

No reason why this shouldn't work

```
 app.get('/cars/:email', async (req, res) => {
   const query = { email: req.params.email };
   const result = await serviceCollection.findOne(query);
   res.send(result);
 });
```

When the "server goes down", is it giving you an error message?

Answer (score 0):

Your email is missing in node js code  you have to grave email from req as like this
**const email = req.query.email**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

the problem is you already have another endpoint with "/cars/" you need to change "/(here)/" ... like "/carsByEmail/:email". This happens when you declare another same endpoint with app.get method. You should try this enter code here

```js
app.get('/carsByEmail/:email', async (req, res) => {
   const query = { email: req.params.email };
   const result = await serviceCollection.findOne(query);
   res.send(result);
 });
```

you already have this endpoint, this two are (1)=> "/cars/:id" and  (2)=> "/cars/:email" the same get method. so that's why it's giving you BSONType error. and it also collaborates with the other same endpoint. So you should change the main endpoint name.. Like  (1)=> "/carsById/:id"   and (2)=>  "/carsByEmail/:email" now everything is perfect withe the same get/put/patch method. just change the main part of the API endpoint. Thank you

```js
app.get('/cars/:id', async (req, res) => {
            const id = req.params.id;
            const query = { _id: ObjectId(id) };
            const result = await serviceCollection.findOne(query);
            res.send(result);
        });
```